# Get row position using data (Datatable Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

So I have this table created with the Jquery Plugin Datatable (http://datatables.net). What I want to do is finding if a row really exists through its data if not I create it. I managed to find how to add a row:

```
$("#Mytable").dataTable().fnAddData([
Name,
Age,
Link,
Schema,
Visite,
Info
]);
```

But I didn't get the info on how to find a row using its elements or what the `<td>` tags contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery in order to get all the rows of your datatable and iterate on it in order to check if you have to add -or not- a new row :

```
var oTable = $("#Mytable").dataTable({whatever discribing your datatable});
//After the declaration of your datatable : 
var rowToAdd = true;
oTable.$('tr').each(function(){
   var td_index = 0;
   $(this).children('td').each(function){
     if($(this).value == mynewdata[td_index])
        rowToAdd = false;
     td_index++;
   }
});
if(rowToAdd)
   oTable.fnAddData([Name,Age,Link,Schema,Visite,Info]);
```

**Edit** Definition of every tds included (not sure of $(this).value but I think if it isn't correct it is not far away ;)

Comment: `every tds of this row match with the row I want to add` : That's exactely what i need to find !!